# Send data to flask using fetch

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

I want to send data to a flask app without using ajax or jquery(only using vanilla js). I found that fetch offers to do the same however, I'm not able to make it work.

### My Code

html code

```
<a href="#" id="link{{i}}" onclick="getdata(this.id)">
<script>
function getdata(id){
    let numberId = id.slice(-1);
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append( {{data.links[numberId]}} );

    fetch("/recipes",
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })
    .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
    .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
    }
   </script>
```

My python code

```
elif request.method == "POST":
    clickedLink = flask.request.args.get("body")
    print(clickedLink)
```

Update:
Some errors I'm receiving.
[image]

Receiving the following error
[image]

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Danila Ganchar Well the data is not being sent, additionally the function that my fetch is sitting inside doesn't seem to be defined for some reason, neither does any other function in the file.

Comment: I think you need to add some `frontend` details(how you register `onclick` etc)